# How to select numbers with precision in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I have a query and in some of columns, it returns numbers, like 1,2,3 and etc but I need to show them as 1,00, 2,00, 3,00 respectfully, how can I achieve it? I tried

```
CAST(2 as FLOAT(2))
```

and

```
ROUND(2, 2)
```

but those didn't work. I also tried to use `to_char`, but I didnt understand how to use masking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your goal is to select a character string that represents the number and that you always want 2 decimal places to be displayed and for the string to respect your session's NLS settings for the decimal separator (whether that is a comma or a period)

```
select to_char( <<the number>>, '0D99' )
  from <<your table>>
```

This will print a leading 0 as well if the number is less than 1.  If you don't want a leading 0, use the "9D99" format mask

Comment: ended up using mask -> 'FM9G999G999G999G990D0'

Answer (score 1):

Set your **nls_numeric_characters** according to your requirement for the separator. Use **TO_CHAR** to format the output.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters=',.';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH DATA(num) AS(
  2  SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT to_char(num, '9D99') FROM DATA;

TO_CH
-----
 1,00
 2,00
 3,00

SQL>
```